# How to implement live chat in ios

Tags: ios, ipad, social-networking, livechat

Is there any tutorial or sample available implementing a live chat iPad application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways for this. You can go through any way for this.
There is a single Objective-C library [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) listed on the XMPP Standards Foundation site

Check this nice tutorial also [Integrating Chat in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server)

Answer (score 0):

For live chat you should use XMPP Framework. You can do this using smartfox server too.